# PHP script POST and retrieve data

Tags: php, ajax, post

I'm very new to PHP and need to create a script that will send login information and then retrieve the results. I've done some searching around but this is the best I could come up with:

```
<?php
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password'
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/json",
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$url = "https://www.example.com/";
$fp = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);

$response = stream_get_contents($fp);
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

I honestly don't know if this is the best approach for what I'm trying to do or if there is a better method. The result is supposed to be a token that I plug into another POST that pulls a specific user from a database to populate a theme based on the user. I also can't use AJAX through jQuery because of problems with IE(go figure). Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: So what is the issue, why you did not mention that ?

Comment: I'm just new to PHP and didn't know if what I had should be working or not. Whenever I pull the script and try to get the data, the result would just say "false"

Answer (score 2):

You can use cUrl:

```
$url = "https://www.example.com/";

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=username&password=password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll give this a shot and see if I can get what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to save the login data in the superglobal `$_SESSION` ? So that way, whenever you need is just to call `$_SESSION['UserLogin'];`